# EXT JS, find a parent with id ending in 

Tags: extjs

I am having a hard time finding this in the EXT.DomQuery Docs, so figured i would post the question here.
It is pretty simple, I have an element and i am just trying to  find the most immediate parent element whose ID ends with 'content-panel'.
Does anyone know the correct syntax for this ?
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this work?

```
element.findParentNode('[id$="content-panel"]')
```